# ASP array element is null and conversion of string to long

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've inherited an ASP project, and I'm a PHP coder with no ASP knowledge.  Sorry if this post is lengthy, I just want to give as much informations as possible.

I'm struggling with this one block of code.

```
Dim resultArray As String()
For Each resultitem In resultArray
    ' Do something with each element of the array
    hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i), resultitem)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Error:

```
Exception!!: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

The solution seems simple.  Check if `resultitem` is null then either break or skip to the next element.

So I tried this:

```
If IsNull(resultitem) Then
    Break
End If
```

Error:

```
BC30451: Name 'IsNull' is not declared.
```

I tried several other alternatives I found online:

- `IsEmpty(resultitem)` - IsEmpty not declared
- `String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultitem)` - index out of bounds error, seems to have no effect
- `resultitem Is Nothing` - index out of bounds
- `Not (Len(resultitem) > 0)` - index out of bounds
- `Len(resultitem) = 0` - index of out bounds

The only thing that seems to come close is:

```
If Not resultitem Then
    Break
End If
```

Error:

```
Exception!!: Conversion from string "some_string_here" to type 'Long' is not valid.
```

If I use `Next` instead of `Break` I get this error:

```
If Not resultitem Then
    Next
End If
```

Error:

```
BC30081: 'If' must end with a matching 'End If'.
```

Help!

I'm going to include the full block of code in case it is helpful

```
Dim isResultArray As Boolean
isResultArray = methodInf.ReturnType.IsArray()
If isResultArray Then
    Dim resultArray As String()
    '*** Invoke the dll function
    resultArray = methodInf.Invoke(REMem, args.ToArray)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each resultitem In resultArray

        If Not resultitem Then
            Response.Write("Found null value.")
            Exit For
        End If

        Response.Write("i: " & i & "<br />")

        hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i), resultitem)
        i = i + 1
        ' i = 6 will cause Get Constituent Name to work
        'If i = 6 Then
        '   Exit For
        'End If
    Next
    outputArray.Add(hash)
Else
    '*** could be boolean, string, long etc.
    Dim result As String
    '*** Invoke the dll function
    result = methodInf.Invoke(REMem, args.ToArray)
    hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(0), result)
    outputArray.Add(hash)
End If
```

Comment: seems to me you get "Index was out of range" when trying to get a value from ReturnTemplateField(i) which is null, not because resultitem is null

Comment: +1 for including what you've attempted on your own (even if it's wrong).  Most of the time when I see posts like this, they don't show nearly this much effort on the part of the OP.

Comment: I think you need to investigate what ReturnTemplateField is (share some more code?) and figure out what you want to do with hash if ReturnTemplateField(i) is null. You could always do something like If Not IsNothing(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i)) Then  hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i), resultitem) End If but you probably need to know why you have nothing in your ReturnTemplateField(i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're not overflowing the index of the collection you're accessing.  Something like this should work:

```
If i < dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField.Length Then

    hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i), resultitem) 

End If
```

Basically, you need to wrap your call to "hash.Add" in this if block to protect against accessing a value that doesn't exist.

Granted, I don't understand the purpose of the code, so you might need to handle the "else" case.  But this should stop the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Turns out it was an arrayList, so I had to use .Count instead of .Length.  ASP, why do you have to make things so complicated?  After going through this process, I have determined that I never want to be an ASP programmer.  Thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: @user1748204 Glad I could help out =)  If it helps, I'm pretty clueless about PHP haha.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the array may be defined incorrectly.

Change this:

```
Dim resultArray As String()
For Each resultitem In resultArray
    ' Do something with each element of the array
    hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i), resultitem)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

To this:

```
Dim resultArray() As String
For Each resultitem In resultArray()
    ' Do something with each element of the array
    hash.Add(dllFunctionObj.ReturnTemplateField(i), resultitem)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

---

Additionally, you may need to define the length of the array, e.g.:

```
Dim resultArray(0 to 9) As String
```

If the length of the array is unknown, you may define it without the minimum and maximum index, but will need to use `ReDim` to assign the minimum and maximum indexes later. One method would be to create the array without a length, count the items that you know will be added to the array, and then use `ReDim` with that count as the length of the array. For example:

```
Dim resultArray() As String
Dim iCount as integer 'Keep track of the count with this variable.

'Enter custom counting script here...Use a loop to count the items that will be used in the array. 

ReDim resultArray(0 to iCount - 1) 'Subtract one from the iCount to match the 0-based index.
```

If you try to call upon a index of an array that has no set length (or use an index greater/less than the size of the array), you will most likely encounter either an "Index out of range" or "Substring out of range" error.

Comment: I could be crazy (I have been known to be), but I don't think it's the resultArray that's throwing the error (since the OP is not accessing it's elements via indices, but is using a foreach loop).  They're trying to access the index of that TemplateField collection via the "i" variable, which is what's more likely to be throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I don't know the length of the array ahead of time.  I tried a variation of the first solution and things worked out.  Thanks for the time spent regardless.